# ¿Cómo centrar el plano cartesiano de una gráfica en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo unas gráficas usando la librería **matplotlib** de **Python**, sin embargo, el plano cartesiano no se ubica en el centro sino en el lateral izquierdo, tal y como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, necesito que el plano cartesiano quede de la siguiente manera (imagen representativa):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Añade el código, por favor, con lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(-10., 10., 0.2)
curva = [x**3-9*x for x in x]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

plt.plot(x,curva)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]